# warning 'no explicit ownership' Issue Archive Project XCode

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, archive, xcode7.2, gcdasyncudpsocket

in Xcode 7.2.1 I have an issue when I archive my project, my app using WebSocket and I'm using the CocoaAsyncSocket Library, the app runs on Simulator or Any device but when archive, xcode show me this errors warnings:

in the class GCDAsyncUdpSocket
in the method:

```
 - (void)getDelegate:(id <GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate>*)delegatePtr delegateQueue:(dispatch_queue_t *)delegateQueuePtr;
```

warnings error:

```
/Users/Dennis/Desktop/WebSocketDennis/CocoaAsyncSocket/Source/GCD/GCDAsyncUdpSocket.m:569:56: Method parameter of type '__autoreleasing id<GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate> *' with no explicit ownership
```

and

```
/Users/Dennis/Desktop/WebSocketDennis/CocoaAsyncSocket/Source/GCD/GCDAsyncUdpSocket.m:569:102: Method parameter of type '__autoreleasing dispatch_queue_t *' (aka 'NSObject<OS_dispatch_queue> *__autoreleasing *') with no explicit ownership
```

I did try another answers like in:

[question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608284/how-to-fix-warning-no-explicit-ownership), [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804435/automatic-reference-counting-pointer-to-non-const-type-nserror-with-no-expl) or [question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814718/handling-pointer-to-pointer-ownership-issues-in-arc)

but how can I fix this ARC issue if I need an ***id delegate*** or ***dispatch_queue_t***

and why this issue appears only when needed archive the project?

**EDIT 1**
someone have any idea for how ARC handles returns by indirection in this case? becocuse the errors warning show only in the methods:

.h file:

```
- (void)getDelegate:(id <GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate>*)delegatePtr delegateQueue:(dispatch_queue_t *)delegateQueuePtr;
- (void)setDelegate:(id <GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate>)delegate delegateQueue:(dispatch_queue_t)delegateQueue;
```

in .m file:

```
- (void)getDelegate:(id  <GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate> * )delegatePtr delegateQueue:(dispatch_queue_t *)delegateQueuePtr
{
    if (dispatch_get_specific(IsOnSocketQueueOrTargetQueueKey))
    {
        if (delegatePtr) *delegatePtr = delegate;
        if (delegateQueuePtr) *delegateQueuePtr = delegateQueue;
    }
    else
    {
        __block id dPtr = NULL;
        __block dispatch_queue_t dqPtr = NULL;

        dispatch_sync(socketQueue, ^{
            dPtr = delegate;
            dqPtr = delegateQueue;
        });

        if (delegatePtr) *delegatePtr = dPtr;
        if (delegateQueuePtr) *delegateQueuePtr = dqPtr;
    }
}

- (void)setDelegate:(id <GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate>)newDelegate delegateQueue:(dispatch_queue_t)newDelegateQueue synchronously:(BOOL)synchronously
{
    dispatch_block_t block = ^{

        delegate = newDelegate;

        #if !OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC
        if (delegateQueue) dispatch_release(delegateQueue);
        if (newDelegateQueue) dispatch_retain(newDelegateQueue);
        #endif

        delegateQueue = newDelegateQueue;
    };

    if (dispatch_get_specific(IsOnSocketQueueOrTargetQueueKey)) {
        block();
    }
    else {
        if (synchronously)
            dispatch_sync(socketQueue, block);
        else
            dispatch_async(socketQueue, block);
    }
}

- (void)setDelegate:(id <GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate>)newDelegate delegateQueue:(dispatch_queue_t)newDelegateQueue
{
    [self setDelegate:newDelegate delegateQueue:newDelegateQueue synchronously:NO];
}

- (void)synchronouslySetDelegate:(id <GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate>)newDelegate delegateQueue:(dispatch_queue_t)newDelegateQueue
{
    [self setDelegate:newDelegate delegateQueue:newDelegateQueue synchronously:YES];
}
```

I can run the project on  iOS simulator and any real device, the problem is only when I want archive the project, if I do Product>Analyze or Product>Build For> Running or Testing, runs perfectly, but when I do Product>Archive or Product> Build For>Profiling the error warning appears

thanks!

Comment: please, someone have any idea for how ARC handles returns by indirection in this case? thanks!

Comment: Please add the code in GCDAsyncUdpSocket, line 569 (and a little bit more) to your Q.

Comment: Have you tried running on a physical device rather than the sim? Wondering if the problem is with archiving, or specific device types/architectures.

Comment: thanks for comment @AminNegm-Awad I edited the question, any Idea? thanks!

Comment: thanks for Comment @BevTheDev I can run the project on any iOS Simulator and Any Real Device the problem appears only when I want Archive the project

Comment: Have you tried `(__autoreleasing id< GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate > *)delegate`?

Comment: It could be a problem with your build settings. If you search for "arc", are any of those settings different between debug and release?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I did try with (__autoreleasing id< GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate > *)delegate, but didn't work, thanks again

Comment: @BevTheDev I did check all "arc" build settings, but are ok, thanks for comment